# IP alias lost when changing main IP

Tags: linux, networking, ip-aliasing

my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.3.75
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.3.0
```

Situation 1:

After linux booted I set an IP alias: `ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.3.111`

Now `ifconfig` reports two IP addresses `192.168.3.75` at `eth0` and `192.168.3.111` at `eth0:0`

When I change main IP to another network: `ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.111` the alias `eth0:0` is **lost**!

Situation 2:

After linux booted I set an IP alias: `ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.4.111`

Now `ifconfig` reports two IP addresses `192.168.3.75` at `eth0` and `192.168.4.111` at `eth0:0`

When I change main IP to another network: `ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.111` the alias `eth0:0` **stays**!

How do I properly change main IP, so all my aliases are not lost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is simple: Stop using the prehistoric `ifconfig`. It is deprecated and it uses deprecated ioctl APIs. What you are hitting is the kernel's compatibility layer, which tries to infer information that `ifconfig` and `route` does not provide.

Use `ip` from the `iproute2` package.  This is what a modern `ifupdown` does anyway (see `ifup -v eth0` to see what i'm talking about).

`ip` and rtnetlink have native capabilities to add several IP addresses to an interface, without using huge obsolete hacks like interfaces aliases which are not interfaces nor aliases.

Oh, and by the way: modern `ifupdown` should be able to support this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.3.75
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.3.0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.3.111
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

And it should do the right thing. Test with `ifup -v eth0` to make sure.

---

Why does the compatibility layer break this way ? That's simple. Consider what a user expect the system to do when it runs `ifconfig eth0 192.0.2.42`:

- Does the user want to add the 192.0.2.42 IP address to the list of available addresses ?
- Does the user want to reset the existing address(es) of the interface so it only have the 192.0.2.42 address ?

Sometimes, the user want the first option. Sometimes, it want the second option (e.g. when changing the configuration completely).  But there is no defined semantics to the SIOCSIFADDR ioctl.

With rtnetlink, there is no ambiguity: You manage a list of addresses with different types (IPv4, IPv6 ...) and you use RTM_NEWADDR to add a address, RTM_DELADDR to remove an existing address (if you specify one) or all addresses of an interface.

And `ip` is a thin wrapper for the rtnetlink API:

- Use `ip addr add 192.168.3.111/24 dev eth0` to add an address.
- Use `ip addr del 192.168.3.111/24 dev eth0` to delete an address.  The operation will fail if the address does not exist.
- Use `ip -4 addr flush dev eth0` to remove all ipv4 addresses.

You can manage IPv6 addresses the same way.  Which is pretty convenient considering that having multiple IPv6 addresses on an interface is just normal behavior.